# Get Custom Attribute on Product List with Flat Catalog

Tags: magento, attributes, catalog, magento-1.9

I got a problem. I tried to use my magento website in Flat Catalog Mode.
But it doesn't work on product list.
I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.infinite_stock' in 'where clause'
```

I've created a custom attribute called "infinte stock" and choose "Used in Product Listing" and "Visible on Prodct View Page on Front-end".

I don't konw what I did wrong...
If someone got idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have reindexed catalog_product_flat after creating your attribute ?

Comment: Yes I've reindexed after.

Answer (score 1):

Get your custom attribute code by logging into the admin panel.
Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes, select your infinite_stock attribute and copy the Attribute Code
For our example the custom attribute code will be infinite_stock

Then try below code.

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('infinite_stock');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

This code will first check if the attribute code exists and gets its value if its there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put this code on `list.phtml` and I manage to get the value when my catalog is NOT on flat mode but I still got my error when I activate Flat product catalog